# cascading Combobox in Devexpress mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have created two partial view each for combo box while I call back by changing first Combo box selection throws error. How to create cascading Combo Box in DevExpress MVC application using C#?

Comment: Show us some code !

Comment: Provide your [mcve] code to show your effort & explain what error you have.